# Select to split one row in various rows given two hours MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, intervals

Hello community how are u doing.
Lets say i have this row in a table

| id | start | end | interval1 | interval2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 55 | 5 |

So id like to create a view where i give the id as condition and it returns me rows from the field start and adding interval1+interval2 until the field end. In this example (12:00:00 + (55 + 5)) it would return

| id | start | end | interval1 | interval2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 55 | 5 |
| 1 | 13:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 55 | 5 |
| 1 | 14:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 55 | 5 |
| 1 | 15:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 55 | 5 |
| 1 | 16:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 55 | 5 |

Im pretty new with mysql and ive been struggling for hours.
Thank u all!

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  also, it makes it easier to answer if you don't keep your table name a secret

Answer (score 0):

For mysql v8, recursive CTE can  be used -

```
with recursive cte(id, starttime,end_1,interval1,interval2) as 
(select * from table_1 union all
select id, addtime(starttime,SEC_TO_TIME((interval1 + interval2)*60)) starttime, end_1, interval1, interval2
from cte
where starttime < end_1)
select * from cte;
```

DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nwgA6GCqmqDi1qPD4S8qe4/0).

Comment: this will produce rows with start > end sometimes ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j6GgPqK2uquxRSydomM7qi/0)); a better where condition is `where addtime(starttime,SEC_TO_TIME((interval1 + interval2)*60)) <= end`

Comment: I didnt know that existed. It works! and its quite easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that in each row interval1 and interval2 may have different values, and we want to display results for more then one ID, or even create a view, only `LATERAL` can do the job for each row separately. It was added in 8.0.14.

```
create view periods as
select mytable.id, addtime(start,SEC_TO_TIME(a*(interval1 + interval2)*60)) starttime, end, interval1, interval2 from mytable, lateral (
with recursive cte as (
   select 0 as a 
   union all 
   select 1+a from cte where a+1<=time_to_sec(subtime(end,start))/((interval1+interval2)*60))
select * from cte
) b
```

and after that

```
select * from periods where id = 3 order by starttime
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ec5eb5292d327562e9dcb2d41249207)